# Is there a way to store multiple values in an enum entry?

Tags: c++, arrays, enums, enumerator

I'm new to C++, and I'm trying to make an enum list of places and they're respective coordinates, but I can't figure out a way to store multiple integer values in one enum entry. Is it possible to do this?

I've done lots of looking around, and I cant find anything that shows how to.

```
enum Places {

    CITY = //coordinates would be here,
    TOWN = //differnt coordinates would be here

};
```

Any help would be great

Comment: Make an array which uses the enum values as indices

Comment: No, `enum`'s are plain numbers.

Comment: Are you sure you don't just want a `class`?

Comment: If you can switch to a different language (like F#), then the answer is yes.  But if you have to stick with C++, then the answer is no.

Comment: Expanding on @Eljay's comment - the language feature being described is a discriminated union

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's not possible (unless you settle for somehow encoding you coordinates into a single integer, which, in my opinion, is an abuse of `enum`).

I suggest using a structure instead:

```
struct fvec2 // "fvec2" = a 2D vector of floats
{
    float x, y;
};

const fvec2 city = {1,2}, town = {1,2};
```